# How to merge only up to a specific commit location in gitlab flow

Tags: git

First let me say that cherry-picking is not the approach I want.

The scenario is like this.

master always has the latest commit.

So, we plan to deploy this production version to a specific commit location.

But merge always gets all commits.

The reason it's not cherry-picked is because it's difficult to know later which commits I pulled.

This is because if you perform a merge later, there will be two commits.

If there are commits from A to Z

Only A to D need to be merged. (There is no need to leave out the middle.)

Which method should I use?

Comment: checkout the A-D commit first,

git checkout -b release-branch <commit-D>

then merge the `release-branch` to the master to deploy

Can this way fix your problem?

Comment: I think this is as simple as merging the commit ID instead of the branch name. So `git merge D` instead of `git merge <branch-name>`.